# Html.BeginForm RouteValueDictionary vs Html.Hidden

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What's the difference between the two methods below to pass parameters to a controller action? When should I use one or the other?

First approach:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", new {orderId = Model.orderID, productId = Model.productID}, FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...
}
```

Second approach:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{ 
    ...

    @Html.Hidden("orderId", model.orderID)
    @Html.Hidden("productID", model.productID)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use submit button to submit the form both approaches would be the same.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

But if you want to use AJAX to submit the form, e.g. using jQuery, then serialize the form. You need to use second approach.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '/Controller/Action',
   data: $('form').serialize()
});
```

## update

If you use route values it will become query parameter and available in `Request.QueryString["key"]`. While if you use hidden input, it will be available in `Request.Form["key"]`.

Both of them are also available if you provide parameter.

```
public ActionResult Action(string key)
```

Comment: Both approaches are definitely not the same, in any scenario.

Comment: @SethMW, I updated my answer, I meant with both approaches the values can be retrieved from parameter.

Comment: @Yuliam: I like your answer but can you make me an example of where I should prefer one approach to the other? For example in terms of security?

Comment: @Alberto, as other also mentioned, RouteValues will become query string, after submitted and go back to the same view, the URL will have additional query string `?key=Value`, if you feel like the user doesn't need to see the parameter, you might want to use hidden field, and URL has ~2000 maximum length, while posting using HTTP post is far longer than that, and both approaches can be intercepted using web debugger tool

Answer (score 2):

The first approach is using [FormExtensions.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx) method override which is appending values to the form submit url:

```
<form action="/ControllerName/ActionName?orderId=<Model.orderID>&productId=<Model.productID>" action="post">
```

Parameters from here could be retrieved from the route parameters collection.

Second approach will simply add two hidden fields which could be bound to the model object passed in and out of controller action.

Answer (score 1):

The first is using the RouteValue dictionary, which will add those values to the URL the form posts to. (They will be added as query string values, unless you have a matching Route rule specified at which point they would be added as '.../orderId/productId'.) This makes the parameters more GET-like.

The second adds input elements to the form in the DOM, which will then be truly POST-ed as form data to the action.

Answer (score 1):

With first approach :

Object Route Values will go to post controller as querystring as shown :"

```
<form action="/ControllerName/ActionName?orderId=1&productID=2" method="post"></form>
```

but with second approach you can get `orderId` and `productID` values from model at post controller.